# So is there a way to get a variable based on product.flavor in gradle to a task?

Tags: android, task, build.gradle

I have done the done the following in my app/build.gradle:

```
android
{
   productFlavors.all {
      ext.projectFlavor = null
   }

   // flavors we support, attention to the version name and version code
   flavorDimensions "default"
   productFlavors {
      oldDashboard {
        versionName "1.0.0"
        versionCode 1
        ext.projectFlavor = "oldDashboard"
      }
      newDashboard {
        versionName "1.0.0"
        versionCode 1
        ext.projectFlavor = "newDashboard"
       }
    }
  }
  dependencies { 
    preBuild.dependsOn writeXml

  }
```

I have the following variables in my project level build.gradle.

```
  ext {
      projectFlavor = 'main'
  }
```

I am including the following task:

```
task writeXml {

   def assetsDirectory = projectFlavor

   inputFile = new File("$projectDir/src/$assetsDirectory/assets/style.json")

}
```

projectFlavor is always the original value of 'main'.

How can I get it to be the value based on the product flavor? It looks like it is just taking the values of the file at run time, not when the project builds.

Answer (score 0):

So I got around the issue by doing a method call:

My Method:

```
ext.callTask = { projectFlavor ->

    return tasks.create("writeXml$projectFlavor", DefaultTask) {
    // style_default.json is parsed in baseUILib and we will only maintain that json as default

    // field definitions
    def matchString = "//.*"
    def inputFile
    def jsonFileString
    def patternComment
    def matcherComment
    def newContent
    def json
    def sw
    def xml
    def file

    // Retailers' customized colors

    def assetsDirectory = projectFlavor

    inputFile = new File("$projectDir/src/$assetsDirectory/assets/style.json")
    jsonFileString = inputFile.text
    patternComment = Pattern.compile(matchString)
    matcherComment = patternComment.matcher(jsonFileString)
    newContent = matcherComment.replaceAll("")
    json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(newContent)

    sw = new StringWriter()
    xml = new MarkupBuilder(sw)
    xml.setDoubleQuotes(true)
    xml.resources() {
        json.colors.each {
            k, v ->
                if (v.contains("#")) {
                    color(name: "${k}", "${v}")
                } else {
                    color(name: "${k}", "@color/" + "${v}")
                }
        }
    }
    file = new File("$projectDir/src/$projectFlavor/res/values/generated_colors.xml")
    file.write(sw.toString())

}

}
```

I call it here in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // Lib files
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // task dependencies
    [android.productFlavors.oldDashboard,
       android.productFlavors.newDashboard].collect {
       it
    }.eachWithIndex {flavorName, index ->
       preBuild.dependsOn callTask(flavorName.name)
    }
   
    //rest of dependencies here.
}
```